# How to save imageData to NSManagedObject property

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

My app downloads images from Flickr and displays them in a CollectionViewController and persists the images in Core Data. I am trying to save imageData to my NSManagedObject context, but I can tell that I am not doing this correctly because I never get to the "else" section of my logic in my cellForRowAt function. Where and how do I update my "Images" NSManagedObject with the imageData property?

Here is my client class:

```
    func getImagesFromFlickr(pin: Pin, context: NSManagedObjectContext, page: Any, completionHandlerForGetImages: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ errorString: String?) -> Void) {

    let methodParameters = [
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Method: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.FlickrPhotosSearch,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.APIKey: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.APIKey,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Format: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.ResponseFormat,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Extras: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.MediumURL,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.NoJSONCallback: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.DisableJSONCallback,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Lat: pin.latitude as Any,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Lon: pin.longitude as Any,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.PerPage: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.PerPage,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Page: page
    ]

    taskForGetImages(methodParameters: methodParameters, latitude: pin.latitude, longitude: pin.longitude) { (results, error) in

        if let error = error {
            completionHandlerForGetImages(false, "There was an error getting the images: \(error)")
        } else {

            // Create a dictionary from the data:

            /* GUARD: Are the "photos" and "photo" keys in our result? */
            if let photosDictionary = results![Constants.FlickrResponseKeys.Photos] as? [String:AnyObject], let photoArray = photosDictionary[Constants.FlickrResponseKeys.Photo] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {

                for photo in photoArray {

                    let image = Images(context: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context)

                    // GUARD: Does our photo have a key for 'url_m'?
                    guard let imageUrlString = photo[Constants.FlickrResponseKeys.MediumURL] as? String else {
                        completionHandlerForGetImages(false, "Unable to find key '\(Constants.FlickrResponseKeys.MediumURL)' in \(photo)")
                        return
                    }

                    // Get metadata
                    let imageURL = URL(string: imageUrlString)!
                    let title = photo["title"] as? String ?? ""

                    // Assign the metadata to images NSManagedObject
                    image.imageURL = String(describing: imageURL)
                    image.pin = pin
                    image.title = title

                    CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context.insert(image)
                }
                CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().saveContext()
            }
            completionHandlerForGetImages(true, nil)
        }
    }
}

func withBigImage(_ urlString: String?, completionHandler handler: @escaping (_ image:UIImage) -> Void){

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { () -> Void in

        if let url = URL(string: urlString!) {
            if let imgData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {

                    performUIUpdatesOnMain {
                        let image = Images(context: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context)
                        image.imageData = imgData as NSData
                        CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().saveContext()
                    }

                    performUIUpdatesOnMain {
                        handler(img)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my cellForItemAt method:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    cell.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
    cell.activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: cell.frame.size.width/2, y: cell.frame.size.height/2)

    performUIUpdatesOnMain {
        cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
    let image = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

    if image.imageData == nil {
        print("Image data doesn't exist")

        FlickrClient.sharedInstance().withBigImage(image.imageURL, completionHandler: { (cellImage) in

            performUIUpdatesOnMain {
                cell.imageView.image = cellImage
                cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        })
    } else {
        print("Image data exists")
        performUIUpdatesOnMain {
            cell.imageView.image = image.image
            cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }

    if let _ = self.selectedIndexes.index(of: indexPath) {
        cell.imageView.alpha = 0.5
    } else {
        cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0
    }
    return cell
}
```

*Note: performUIUpdatesOnMain is my GCD DispatchQueue.main.async method.

I believe this might be an issue with background and main queue issues, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your sqlite database if the image data gets stored? You can use [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) if you are working with the simulator.
Do you really need so store your images inside coredata, the better approach is to store only the imagepath/metadata inside coredata and the plain image on the filesystem.

Anyway. If there is no data written into the sqlite database you can try using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to convert the image and save the converted data

```
let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 1)
```

Comment: I am making this app for a class and saving the imageData in Core Data is a requirement. I actually already have it working with everything BUT that feature. I've seen this method you mention above... is that suggesting I should download the imageData, turn it into a UIImage and then turn the UIImage back into imageData to save it? Seems I should be able to save the imageData to Core Data when I first extract the imageData from URL, no?